# Undefined ADT in r5rs

Tags: import, module, scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm writing an ADT in r5rs and I'm using DrRacket. I put `#lang r5rs` at the top of my file and chose *Determine Language from Source* from DrRacket, but it tells me my ADT is undefined. I'm using DrRacket version 6.0. It's the first time I've had this and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**My ADT**

```
#lang r5rs
(#%require "queue.rkt") ;A required file
(#%provide (all-defined))

(define (my-ADT)
    (let ((val1 '())
          (val2 '()))

    (define (foo) ...)
    (define (bar) ...)

    (define (dispatch msg)
        (case msg
            ((foo) foo)
            ((bar) bar)
            (else "Unknown message")))

    dispatch))
```

When I try to create an instance of my-ADT I get the following output: `my-ADT: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition`

When I remove `#lang r5rs` from the top and choose *R5RS* as language in DrRacket, it seems to work. But then my `queue.rkt` file still has `#lang r5rs` at the top and *Determine Language from Source*. When I remote `#lang r5rs` and choose *R5RS* as language in that file also, I get the following in the `my-ADT` file:

```
default-load-handler: expected a `module' declaration
found: something else
in: #<path:/Users/path/path/path/queue.rkt>
```

Answer (score -1):

The error

> my-ADT: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition

normally indicates that the function `my-ADT` was used before it was defined.
That is, one must place all definitions on top of the file and place the expressions below.

Your example above has no uses of `my-ADT` so if you get this error, the problem might be in "queue.rkt". Can you run "queue.rkt" without errors?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine. But when I remove `#lang r5rs` from the top of the `queue.rkt` file, it gives me the second error.

Comment: Could you post the two actual files.